# Why does Clair own so many CRT TV's?

Tags: rampage

In *Rampage (2018)*, There are lots of CRT TV's in Claire's room. She works in the gene manipulation company (Energyne).

[image]

I dont understand why does she owns so  many CRT TV's?

Comment: If those are CRTs, they're old ones -- TVs had nearly straight edges and sharpish corners for 20+ years before CRTs became obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

Those aren't CRT TVs. They're back-lit shelves that she uses to hold her mathoms.

You see the *opposite* side of one of them as she enters the room.

[image: artifact displayed in front of back-lit shelf]

[image: view of several of those artifacts]